# batch script to create multiple m3u8 manifest files

Tags: windows, batch-file

im trying to create a batch script to create multiple m3u8 manifest files. 
here is some pseudo code for what im trying to do

```
for (int i= 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
{
    write preset lines to file.
    for (int x = i x < i+10; x++)
    {
        write string + x in line to file
    }
    write end of file line to file
}
```

this is what i have so far. i am having issues with the inner for loop. how can i make it run from x to x + 10?

```
@echo on

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set x=0

for /L %%x IN (0,1,5) do (
set file="index%%x.m3u8"

@echo #EXTM3U>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-VERSION:3>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD>>!file!

set n=%x%
for /L %%n IN (n, 1, %x%+10) do (
    @echo #EXTINF:10.00000,>>!file!
    @echo fileSequence!n!.ts>>!file!

)

@echo #EXT-X-ENDLIST>>!file!

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing environment variables with loop variables. The two have nothing to do with each other.

Try the following modification of your script:

```
@echo on

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set x=0

for /L %%x IN (0,1,5) do (
set file="index%%x.m3u8"

@echo #EXTM3U>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-VERSION:3>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0>>!file!
@echo #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD>>!file!

set /a n=%%x+10
for /L %%n IN (%%x, 1, !n!) do (
    @echo #EXTINF:10.00000,>>!file!
    @echo fileSequence%%n.ts>>!file!

)

@echo #EXT-X-ENDLIST>>!file!

)
```

I'm not sure why you are setting the echo on at the beginning and then suppressing individual `echo`s, but you could simplify the script a bit by applying both the suppression and the redirection to blocks instead of individual commands. In particular, the series of `echo`s in the main loop could be rewritten like this:

```
@(
    echo #EXTM3U
    echo #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
    echo #EXT-X-VERSION:3
    echo #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
    echo #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
)>>!file!
```

The inner loop's `echo`s could be transformed into a block in a similar fashion. The indentation inside the block is optional, of course.

Comment: thanks your modification worked. i just had echo on to see what was going on. turned it off now.